# Makefiles, targets as dependencies

Tags: makefile, target

I'm new to Makefiles and I'm trying to debug something that extends over multiple Makefiles.

> target2: target1
>
> command 1

Target 1 builds the source code (takes about ~4 hours). Target 2 is simply supposed to copy resulting files into certain directories.

I've already made target 1. When I immediately try to make target 2, it seems to think it is missing some files/libraries and rebuilds for ~5-10 mins. The files have not been moved or changed. I can executed target 2 immediately after target 1 and it will ALWAYS rebuild for a few minutes.

Target 1 and command 1 are creating the same directory. Is it possible that the timestamp on this directory is causing the rebuilding of these libraries? Or is it only files that will trigger rebuilding with timestamp discrepancy?

Comment: Unclear to me. Could you give more details on these two targets ? What do they do exactly ? Could you give a MWE ?

Answer (score 3):

Targets are actually filenames. The recipes (commands) must create or update that target file otherwise make considers that target missing or out of date and will try to rebuild it on the next run; unless it is a phony target which gets rebuilt every time.

Invoke `make` with `-d` option to see which targets it is building and why.

Comment: What do you mean, targets are actually filenames? This target 2 definitely does not create a file. It creates a bunch of directories and copies the files created from target 1.

Comment: Well, then `target2` must be a phony target and it must depend on those directories; or be a directory itself that contains those other directories.

Comment: _targets are actually filenames_: `target2: target1` tells make to build file `target1` first and then it can build file `target2`. Only phony targets do not create files.

Comment: Okay, so I looked into the manual for make, so my grasp of rules, targets and dependencies is a lot better. Target 1 creates dozens of files but none of the files are named 'Target 1'. 80% of the time I get to Target 2, Target 1 has already been made. This is just a check to make sure that Target 1 has been completed. What happens in situations like these? The files need by Target 2 which are created by Target 1 already exist. But a file with the name 'Target 1' does not.

Comment: @user3816949 Not clear what you are trying to do. There are a few ways to deal with recipes which produce multiple files, but often re-structuring the makefile correctly naturally solves the issue. Post your makefile.

Answer (score 1):

See, GNU make treats all target names as file names by default, so that you can generate some file from the list of prerequisites, like in example below the `main.o` object file will be generated by compiling `main.c` with `main.h`

```
main.o : main.c defs.h
    gcc -c main.c
```

However this is not always what you want to do, sometimes you want to have a target named `foo` that does something that's need to be done prior to execution of target `bar`, this is totally ok except you need to tell make that `foo` is not a file name so that it will not attempt to generate file named `foo`. What you need here is called a `.PHONY` target. A phony target is one that is not really the name of a file; rather it is just a name for a recipe to be executed when you make an explicit request. [GNU Make Manual on Phony Targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html)

```
.PHONY: foo
   foo: bar
```

In the example above `make` is told not to treat target foo as a filename and therefore not to attempt to generate the file named `foo`.

In your case the `target1` may depend on a [target that has no recipe](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Force-Targets.html)
or you may have a file that has the same name as `target1` so that `make` is always attempting to build this file instead (in this case you need a `.PHONY` target), or eventually you may have timestamps or object files somehow altered after `target1` is built so that `make` considers it needs to be rebuilt anew.

Also, in your `target1` you may be building something that `make` cannot analyze, thus being unable to tell if it is already built; this includes working with certain types of archives, generating or transforming text, calling another build systems (like e.g. `ant`) in subroutines, etc.